# Edit Existing Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

Is there any way to inherit and existing Syntax for a custom one?
As I would like to have a custom syntax but don't want to start from zero.

I already found this: [How do I add features to a syntax definition in Sublime Text without editing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314417/how-do-i-add-features-to-a-syntax-definition-in-sublime-text-without-editing-it)
but I couldn't get it to work as it is not detailed explained.

If this is not possible where would I find the file for the Go language syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could copy the `Go.tmLanguage` file, rename it to whatever you want, and then make whatever changes you want to it. You would still need to save that file in your `Packages` folder.

To easily find the file, I recommend you install [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) through Package Control. Once you have that installed, do the following steps:

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open up the command palette.
2. Type `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `Go` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Using the arrow keys, go down to the file named `Go.tmLanguage` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should open up the syntax highlighting file for the Go language.